# Does loading an image take longer than rendering a character?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, load

Rails 4.0.10: I have a page with a list of records, which will probably end up being a few thousand records long. I want to add a delimiter, which will print after each record.

I'm considering using a image for this delimiter. Would loading an image after every record take significantly longer than just adding a comma after every record?

**Here are the two scenarios:**

**1.)**

```
<% Records.all.each do |r| %>
  <%= r.name %>
  <%= image_tag("Delimiter.jpg") %>
<% end %>
```

**2.)**

```
<% Records.all.each do |r| %>
  <%= r.name %>&nbsp,&nbsp
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Using an image between each record requires the asset pipeline to fetch that image each time, which incurs substantial overhead.

As a rule of thumb, it's probably not a great idea to display thousands of images in a single view.

Comment: Do you know of a different way to use a custom delimiter?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with displaying an image after each record as you're intending to do.  The code that you have provided under Scenario 1 will certainly do this.  The issue, rather, is with displaying that many records with images in a single view.  Consider paginating the records to spread the rendering load out to multiple identical views.